# couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes-executor-debug.so after upgrading from React-Native 0.65.0 to 0.70.4 on Android

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, mobile

After upgrading React Native project from 0.65.0 to 0.70.4 I end up in a problem with crashing app on start. The error appears in both debug and release build but in release build error cause app to freeze on splash screen. I tried all available solutions online but nothing helped.

Build.gradle:

```
project.ext.react = [
enableHermes: true,
enableVmCleanup: false,
]

apply from: '../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle'

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get('enableHermes', true)
def reactNativeArchitectures() {
def value = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeArchitectures")
return value ? value.split(",") : \["armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a"\]
}
```

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.0')
    
    implementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.4+'
    
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
    
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:' // From node_modules
    
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
    
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.6.0'
    
    
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22@aar'
    implementation project(':react-native-config')
    
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }
    
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }
    
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }
    
    huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:6.3.0.302'
    
    if (enableHermes) {
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:+") { // From node_modules
            exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
        }
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }

}
```

Output of npx react-native info

> System: OS: macOS 12.6.1 CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M1 Pro Memory: 101.31 MB / 16.00 GB Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh Binaries: Node: 16.14.2 - /usr/local/bin/node Yarn: Not Found npm: 7.21.1 - ~/projects/uc-chameleon-nova-portal-app/node_modules/.bin/npm Watchman: Not Found Managers: CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /Users/urosuzelac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/bin/pod SDKs: iOS SDK: Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 16.0, macOS 12.3, tvOS 16.0, watchOS 9.0 Android SDK: Not Found IDEs: Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335 Xcode: 14.0.1/14A400 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild Languages: Java: 11.0.16.1 - /usr/bin/javac npmPackages: @react-native-community/cli: Not Found react: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0 react-native: 0.70.4 => 0.70.4 react-native-macos: Not Found npmGlobalPackages: react-native: Not Found

After starting the app there is just Splash Screen in freezed state. This happens only in release build. In debug build error is just shown in Logcat.

Error:

> couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes-executor-debug.so SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.a[root = /data/data/com.ucnewsportal/lib-main flags = 1] SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.d[root = /data/app/com.ucnewsportal-sPK_xK9tZWkhxvAZOwVmJA==/lib/arm64 flags = 0] SoSource 2: com.facebook.soloader.d[root = /system/lib64 flags = 2] SoSource 3: com.facebook.soloader.d[root = /vendor/lib64 flags = 2] Native lib dir: /data/app/com.ucnewsportal-sPK_xK9tZWkhxvAZOwVmJA==/lib/arm64 result: 0